# What is formal notation for rounding to the nearest hundredth?

Tags: notation

For example, if =(X*Y), how would you denote formally that the  is to be rounded to the nearest hundredth in this operation?

Comment: What makes you think that there is  such a "formal" notation?

Comment: What would you choose that is least cumbersome and not easily confused with something else?

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+ask+a+good+question). If you add in some context (where does this question come from?), your question will be better received.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not avare of any notation, but you can of course, for your work, define one. For example, let's define:
$$ \mathrm{rd}_{100}(x) := 100\left\lfloor\frac{x}{100} + \frac 12\right\rfloor $$
Then, for example
$$ \mathrm{rd}_{100}(102) = 100\left\lfloor 1.02 + 0.5\right\rfloor = 100. $$

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You are rounding to the nearest *hundred* but OP wants to round to the nearest *hundredth*.

Comment: @MarkDominus Thank you very much, will correct my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For rounding to the nearest *hundredth*, we have:

$$\mathrm{rd}_{1/100}(x) := \frac{1}{100}\left\lfloor100x + \frac 12\right\rfloor $$

This is how the formula works. First multiply by $100$ so that the hundredth digit of $x$ becomes the unit digit. Then add $\frac{1}{2}$ and round down (that's what the floor function does). If the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $x$ (call it $u$) satisfies $0 ≤ u < \frac{1}{2}$, then $u + \frac{1}{2} < 1$, and so the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_function) leaves only the integer part, rounding it down. Conversely, if $\frac{1}{2} ≤ u < 1$, then $u + \frac{1}{2} > 1$, and so the integer part is increased by $1$, rounding it up.

The last step is to convert the unit digit back into hundredths, which is done by multiplying everything by $\frac{1}{100}$. Let's try this process with $x = 23.456$:

$$100x = 2345.6 \implies 100x + \frac{1}{2} = 2346.6 \implies \lfloor100x + \frac{1}{2}\rfloor = 2346$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{100}\lfloor100x + \frac{1}{2}\rfloor = 23.46$$

and this is correct as $23.456$ rounds up to $23.46$.